# How to reference Redux types in index.d.ts typescript definition file?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, intellisense, typescript-typings

I want to create an `index.d.ts` file that reference some types from the popular NPM package known as `redux`.

#### Things that I have tried already:

*(at the top of my `index.d.ts` file)*

1. `/// <reference path="../../../node_modules/redux/index.d.ts" />`

This doesn't work. I suspect it's because the `redux/index.d.ts` file doesn't declare a namespace at all. When I edit `redux/index.d.ts` file and wrap everything in there with a `declare namespace Redux { ... }`, everything works fine. I am on `redux@^4.0.0`.

2. `/// <reference types="redux" />`

This doesn't work unless I install the NPM package `@types/redux/@3.6.31`, which has old out of date typings that don't match the ones that are published. The latest version of `@types/redux` package is just a deprecated placeholder that says to use the official `redux` package typings (which don't work).

3. `import { Middleware } from "redux";`

When I put the `import` statement shown above into my `index.d.ts` file, every declaration in the file broke (i.e. every other place where I was depending on my own `index.d.ts` file for types stopped reading any types at all from it.) From what I have read, putting an `import` statement at the type of a `d.ts` file causes Typescript to consider that file a module, not a definition file.

#### Bad (IMO) workarounds that kinda work but not really:

1. Installing NPM package `@types/redux@3.6.31` instead of the latest deprecated placeholder version of `@types/redux`.
2. Editing my copy of `node_modules/redux/index.d.ts` to wrap everything in a namespace, e.g. `declare namespace Redux { ... }`.

#### Other information:

My project was bootstrapped with `create-react-app` v2 as a JavaScript project. I am simply using `d.ts` files to document some interfaces. My editor is VSCode latest/stable.

Comment: Hi, Have you tried with `https://redux.js.org/basics/usagewithreact`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since typescript 2.9 ([see section on import types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-9.html)) you can use `import()` to use the type definition files without actually importing the module itself. For example this definition will work using the `Action` type from the redux package:

```
declare function createCustomAction(): import("redux").Action
```

No need to reference anything at the top with the triple slash directive.

Comment: I found this tactic earlier and I actually use it all the time in my JSDoc comments. Since it does work, I'll award the points. However, it ended up not being the answer for my particular situation. You can see what I did instead here - https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/3231#issuecomment-444554348